# Disable plugin per user role

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I must disable a discount plugin for certain user role, I have wrote this and put in the child-theme `functions.php`

```
global $woocommerce;

get_currentuserinfo();
global $current_user;

if ($current_user->ID) {
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if ($user_role == 'B2B') {
         deactivate_plugins('/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payment-discounts/woocommerce-payment-discounts.php', false);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, why? Is it correct? and the deactivation is only for the user session?

Comment: What hook are you using to execute this code?

Comment: no hook, i've insert it in the funcion.php, because i don't know what can be the right hook to use.

Comment: Personally I think you're going the wrong way about it - it might be worth explaining _why_ you want to disable the plugin for a particular role?

Comment: If it did work, `deactivate_plugins` would affect all users on your site, not just the `B2B` user.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I don't want to disable the plugin you see in the code, it was only a test, but i want disable a plugin that apply a payment-gateway discount(woocommerce-payment-discounts), but i don't want this discount for user that are not 'B2B', is it clear? Now i edit the qustion with correct plugin name.

Comment: @TomC how can i disable the plugin for the 'user session'? So, now it seems work.

Comment: Okay, in which case you don't actually want to disable the _plugin_, there should be a filter/action in WooCommerce that allows you set which gateways are available based on certain conditions.

Comment: I can assure that trying to disable the plugin conditionally is the wrong way to go about it - WooCommerce provide you with an API for this exact reason.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic i think that this in not the case, because the payment gateway are the same for all the user, but only b2b can have the discount

Comment: Still, there should be an entry point within the plugin to say "if user is not b2b, hide this discount". You are on a one way ticket to debugging hell if you pursue this business of conditionally deactivating plugins.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic can you provide me an example of what you want to tell with 'WooCommerce provide you with an API for this exact reason'? i'm not very expert in wordpress/php coding, sorry

Comment: i know can be very hard the solution of conditioinally deactivate plugin, but i can't find other easy solution, i've tried to mod a plugin and insert a conditionally discount for user role and payment gateway, but don't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `wc_payment_discounts_apply_discount filter`.

Try something like the following:

```
function remove_privato_discounts() { 
    global $woocommerce; 
    get_currentuserinfo(); 
    global $current_user; 
    if ($current_user->ID) { 
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles; 
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles); 
        if ( $user_role !== 'b2b') { 
            $discount = 0; 
            $woocommerce->cart->discount_total = $discount; 
            return true; // Do not apply discount to privato 
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
add_filter( 'wc_payment_discounts_apply_discount', 'remove_privato_discounts');
```

Comment: Great - let me know the changes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: sorry but seems that now dont't work! i don't know why, but yesterday it worked fine

Comment: function remove_privato_discounts() {
 global $woocommerce;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 global $current_user;

 if ($current_user->ID) {
     $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
     $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

     if ( $user_role != 'b2b') {
        $discount = 0;
        $woocommerce->cart->discount_total = $discount;
            return true; // Do not apply discount to privato
            } 
        
 }
 return false;
}
add_filter( 'wc_payment_discounts_apply_discount', 'remove_privato_discounts');

Comment: sorry iv'e give you the code on the previus message but it isn't formatted

Comment: It looks like you're using the compare wrong here: `if ( $user_role != 'b2b')`  as it should probably be: `if ( $user_role !== 'b2b') { `
I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: :( don't work. There is a motive to see why it don't work? The strange thing is that friday it worked fine. any idea? i don't have update nothing.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. How are you testing? Logging in as different users? Also, I don't have much experience of woocommerce and when the actions are called. You could try a different one such as `woocommerce_calculate_totals` instead of `wc_payment_discounts_apply_discount` 
Refer to: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not "deactivate" plugins based on any condition since your code will run only after the plugin have been already initialized, and you can't reverse the initialization.

You should target disabling a specific functionality of the plugin, but unless it has a documentation which specifically suggests how to do it, I would stay away from doing such a thing as some functionality might depend on another, and disabling part of it might leave the whole system in a non stable state with unforeseen implications. At the very minimum you should make sure you understand how the whole plugin works before doing such a thing. In addition you should be prepared that future upgrades of the plugin will not work the same way and will cause your code to break.

Comment: See the other answer and relative comment, it's the right way, but there is  a problem because that solution worked fine since 2 day ago, so now with no motivation seems that not work

Comment: @antlego this is an answer to the on-topic part of your question, the other answer is to the off=topic part of your question.